# Filter Array by Multiple Matching Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have been searching through stackoverflow questions to try and understand how to filter an array by multiple matching values.

My Array:

```
[{"time":"2016-11-30 02:45:00","signal":"Buy","symbol":"AUDNZDecn","price":"1.04605","timeframe":"M15","epoch":"1480473900","candel":"M151480481100"},{"time":"2016-11-30 02:41:00","signal":"Sell","symbol":"AUDJPYecn","price":"84.08700","timeframe":"M1","epoch":"1480473660","candel":"M11480480860"},{"time":"2016-11-30 02:24:59","signal":"Buy","symbol":"EURNZDecn","price":"1.48820","timeframe":"M5","epoch":"1480472699","candel":"M51480479900"}]
```

You can see there are 3 timeframes: M1, M5, M15

I am able to use the following code to filter by a single "timeframe":

```
var j = j.filter(function(el) {
            return el.timeframe == timeframe;
});
```

**Note:** j is equal to a JSON parsed server response from an AJAX query that talks to a php script, which passes back a JSON response, aka the array above.

**Goal:** What I want to understand how to do is filter by multiple "timeframe" values of the array at a time, so that when a user clicks a checkbox for a combination of any of the three timeframes, I can pull the value from the checkboxes and filter the array by whatever combination of checkboxes the user had selected. ex. "M1", "M5", "M15", "M1,M5" or M1,M15" or M5,M15" or "M1,M5,M15" and so on.

The new array that is returned/filtered will get passed to a jquery each loop, that will then go through the data and append the data to a div. (I have this part working already)

Appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Do you want to just push the value into a new array if the user clicks on it? where is your event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [**`Array.prototype.filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [**`Array.prototype.some`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to filter out the results - see demo below:

```js
var array = [{"time":"2016-11-30 02:45:00","signal":"Buy","symbol":"AUDNZDecn","price":"1.04605","timeframe":"M15","epoch":"1480473900","candel":"M151480481100"},{"time":"2016-11-30 02:41:00","signal":"Sell","symbol":"AUDJPYecn","price":"84.08700","timeframe":"M1","epoch":"1480473660","candel":"M11480480860"},{"time":"2016-11-30 02:24:59","signal":"Buy","symbol":"EURNZDecn","price":"1.48820","timeframe":"M5","epoch":"1480472699","candel":"M51480479900"}];

function filterResults(arr) {
  return array.filter(function(el) {
    return arr.some(function(e) {
      return el.timeframe == e;
    });
  });
}

// pass the required timeframes to filter here
var result = filterResults(['M1','M5']);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: @user3259138 let me know if this solved your query, thanks!

Comment: I think this is the track I need to follow. What I am trying to figure out how to do is take the values of the checkboxes once I have used jquery to check if they are checked or not, and if they are checked put the checked ones into an array, which I would then pass to the function

Comment: @user3259138 good to know the filtering part is good to go now, could you please upvote and close this question, thanks!